# How to dynamically add height to a div containing responsive images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a simple jquery image slider placed in a responsive container.  The slider is working responsively, however the height is set in pixels which looks good at its maximum viewport width, but as you can imagine leaves way too much distance between slider and content at smaller viewport widths.

I am wondering if there is a simple way using CSS or jQuery to dynamically set the height of the div containing the image slider so that it looks good for all viewport widths.

the jQuery:

```js
        function slideSwitch() {
            var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active');

            if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV:last');

            var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
                : $('#slideshow DIV:first');

            $active.addClass('last-active');

            $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
                .addClass('active')
                .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
                    $active.removeClass('active last-active');
                });
        }

        $(function() {
            setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
        });
```

the CSS:

```css
        .responsive-container {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .responsive {
            display: block;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #slideshow {
            position:relative;
            height: 60%;
        }

        #slideshow div {
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            z-index:8;
            opacity:0.0;
            background-color: #FFF;
        }

        #slideshow div.active {
            z-index:10;
            opacity:1.0;
        }

        #slideshow div.last-active {
            z-index:9;
        }

        #slideshow div img {
            display: block;
            border: 0;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
```

the HTML:

```html
<div id="slideshow" class="responsive-container">
    <div class="active">
        <img class="responsive" src="img/slider/image1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" />  
    </div>

    <div>
        <img class="responsive" src="img/slider/image2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <img class="responsive" src="img/slider/image3.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
    </div>                            
</div>
```

Is there a way to dynamically add height to:

```
<div id="slideshow" class="responsive-container">
```

I don't know if it matters but the max image size is: 531px width x 400px height.

Comment: do you want to add the height at certain point or whenever resize happens?

Comment: I want to set the height based on the height of the image.

Comment: And, the height of the image is determined by the viewport width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Discrete Height Transitions

CSS [Media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) would allow you to set discrete widths at which the height changes.

```
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  #slideshow {
    height: whatever;
  }
}
```

For an example of how these work (if you're unfamiliar with them) resize your browser on the CSS Tricks website (see the above link). You'll see the layout change when you reach certain widths. That's media queries in action.

## Continuous Height Transitions

For continuous height transitions, you'll need to turn to Javascript. Here's a little jQuery setup that might help you get started. [**View it on JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/aq3uE/)

**javascript**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  winWidth = $(window).width();
  $("#resize").height(winWidth*.3);
});
```

Comment: Media queries aren't what I'm looking for since it wouldn't be a fluid transition of height.

Comment: you can add media queries with max-height and min-height instead of width

Comment: Added a little jQuery code for continuous transitions. Is that what you're looking for, Raphael? And thanks, @DavidChase!

Comment: I think so but I am trying to understand it. I think one piece is missing, however.  On resize, everything is great.  But I want the height to be correct on the first load as well no matter what viewport you are on.  For example, on a desktop viewport, height is something, and smaller on mobile viewports.  Does this do that?

Comment: Is there anything that can select the width/height of an image or an element rather than the window?

Comment: [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) can be used on anything. Replace $(window) with whatever you want.